# Material Ui unstyled asset flashes once every while before rendering with SSR using NextJS

Tags: material-ui, next.js

I have minimized the page to only mateiral ui component and its rendering page but the problem still exists. when I refresh the page, every once in a while a big star flashes before the page is rendered. i suspect it is un-styled star of the mateiral-ui rating component. as I add more imports and complexity to the page, the rate of the star appearing increases. I was wondering if what i'm doing is wrong

```
        import Rating from "@material-ui/lab/Rating";

        function Event() {
          return (<Rating
                    size="large"
                    readOnly={true}
                    defaultValue={5}
                    precision={0.5}
                />
            );
        }

        export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
            return {props:{}}
        }


        export default Event
```

using nextjs version 9.3 
express code:

```
    app.get('/event/:title/:id', async (request, response) => {
        const data = {}
        return next.render(request, response, '/event/Event', data);
    });
```

Comment: Have you properly set up Material-UI server rendering in `_app.js` and `_document.js` as shown in this [example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs)?

Comment: i had not! thank you

Answer (score -1):

It's important to provide the page with the required CSS, otherwise, the page will render with just the HTML then wait for the CSS to be injected by the client, causing it to flicker (FOUC). To inject the style down to the client:

1. Create a fresh, new ServerStyleSheets instance on every request.
2. Render the React tree with the server-side collector.
3. Pull the CSS out.
4. Pass the CSS along to the client.

On the client-side, the CSS will be injected a second time before removing the server-side injected CSS. You can see how to do so in this [example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs).

More about [Server Rendering with Material UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/examples/nextjs)